# PL/SQL Loop issue with Cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am trying to create a PL/SQL script that selects the last name and salary of an employee from the table employees. I have a cursor that stores the data and I fetch the cursor which then inserts the data into a new table called BIG_MONEY. I have a user input that selects the number of employees the loop will run through and the loop ends when it reaches the figure they provided.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DROP TABLE BIG_MONEY;

ACCEPT NumberOfStaff

CREATE TABLE BIG_MONEY (
last_name VARCHAR2(10),
salary NUMBER(7, 2)
);

DECLARE V_EMP_ID employees.employee_id%TYPE;
V_EMP_LASTNAME employees.last_name%TYPE;
V_EMP_SALARY employees.salary%TYPE;

CURSOR EMP_Cursor IS
SELECT employee_id, last_name, salary
FROM employees
ORDER BY salary DESC last_name ASC


BEGIN 
OPEN EMP_Cursor;

LOOP 
FETCH EMP_Cursor INTO V_EMP_ID, V_EMP_LASTNAME, V_EMP_SALARY;

INSERT INTO BIG_MONEY (last_name, salary)
VALUES (V_EMP_LASTNAME, V_EMP_SALARY)

EXIT WHEN EMP_Cursor%ROWCOUNT = '&NumberOfStaff';

DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE
('Employee' || TO_CHAR (V_EMP_ID) || 'last name is' || TO_CHAR (V_EMP_LASTNAME)
|| 'and makes' || TO_CHAR (V_EMP_SALARY) || 'a month');

END LOOP;
CLOSE EMP_Cursor;
```

What am I doing wrong here? I would assume my logic is correct but the syntax is where I'm making a mistake.

Comment: You haven’t `end;`ed your plsql anonymous block (don’t forget the forward slash to submit it to the database). Also should you be treating the user input as a string - it should really be a number?

Comment: moreover end the insert statement with a semi-colon.

Comment: I truly hope is is a poorly-thought-out homework assignment.  In a real business setting there is zero reason to create a table to just hold a subset of some other table.  Especially when the overall description indicates that said table would need to be dropped and recreated every time some other "user" needed his own data.